# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.example.demo.pojo.PurchaseOrder.orderNo to java.lang.Integer

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to persist an entity using springboot data JPA. Faced this issue stating cannot set int field to java.lang.Integer.Below are my classes.

**PurchaseOrder.java**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "PurchaseOrderTable")
@Component
public class PurchaseOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int orderNo;
    @Column
    private String billNo;
    @Column
    private String purchageShop;
    @Column
    private String gstNo;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProductPurchase.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductPurchase> products;
    @Column
    private int totalPrice;
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime purchaseDate; ...
```

**ProductPurchase.java**

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "ProductPurchaseTable")
public class ProductPurchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private int quantityPurchased;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PurchaseOrder.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private int orderNo;
    @Column
    private float totalProductPrice;
    @Column
    private String productName;
    @Column
    private String productBrand;
    @Column
    private String productSize;
    @Column
    private String unit;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private int unitPrice;
```

Reository:

```
@Repository
public interface PurchaseRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, Integer> {
```

I faced this exception while persisting the entity.

**Note:** I am using Springboot with JPA and database is in memory H2 db.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id needs to be an `Integer`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

You also need to make the same change in `ProductPurchase`

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = PurchaseOrder.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Integer orderNo;
```

or, even better:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="orderNo")
private PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;
```

I would also suggest to change the `id` of `ProductPurchase` to `Long`.

In general, I would avoid having a primitive type as an identifier because then you cannot check if the id is null for newly created entities, you will have to check if it's bigger than 0.

Comment: if i will make int to Integer, then the exception is coming like Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set Integer field com.example.demo.pojo.PurchaseOrder.orderNo to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Hello @Davide, I am facing a similar issue with my code, I've changed the 'id' field to Long and I've added your first approach (set targetEntity class), but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Without seeing the entities, I cannot tell. If you publish a failing test somewhere, I will have a look